# In Pig, Flattening a bag into a single line

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

In my Pig script (0.9.2), my final output looks like this:

`final: {email: chararray,{(name: chararray,percent: double)}}`

where for every email address I have up to 3 names and scores.  So, the output would look something like this:

`joe@smith.com {(Joe Smith, 0.5),(Joseph, 0.1), (Joey, 0.1)}`

What I'd really like to do is flatten this into tabbed delimted values (no parentheses or curly braces) to make it easier to pull into a MySQL table like this:

`joe@smith.com  Joe Smith   0.5 Joseph  0.1 Joey    0.1`

How can I accomplish this in Pig?  Or do I have to write a custom UDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a Java UDF that works pretty well for a bag of tuples.  The Tuple.toDelimitedString is the key.

```
public class BagToString extends EvalFunc<String> {

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        DataBag bag = (DataBag) input.get(0);
        Iterator<Tuple> bagIT = bag.iterator();
        String delimiter = "\t";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(bagIT.hasNext()){
            Tuple tupleInBag = bagIT.next();
            sb.append(tupleInBag.toDelimitedString(delimiter)).append(delimiter);
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to write a custom udf for this. You can do that easily in a language like Python. Just do something like:

```
@outputSchema("flat_bag:bag{}")
def flattenBag(bag):
    flat_bag = [item for tup in bag for item in tup]
    return flat_bag
```

Just throw that into a .py file and load it like:

```
REGISTER '/path/to/udfs.py' using jython as py_funcs;
```

And then use it like:

```
final1 = FOREACH final GENERATE email, py_funcs.flattenBag($1);
```

Comment: Eli, wouldn't this still have the {} around the items?

Comment: My bad. Misread that last requirement. You can just FLATTEN() what's returned and get what you want that way, I think.